# Save button not working in custom module form

Tags: magento, magento2

Created a custom module edit form in Magento Admin using uicomponent, but when I click on save button it redirects to the same edit page and not on the action page I specified when created the save button. It keeps redirecting to the edit page with an undefined parameter in URL after key parameter. Am I missing something?? Following is the code I used to generate the buttons.

```
<item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string"><Vendor>\<Module>\Block\Adminhtml\Listings\Edit\BackButton</item>
            <item name="delete" xsi:type="string"><Vendor>\<Module>\Block\Adminhtml\Listings\Edit\DeleteButton</item>
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string"><Vendor>\<Module>\Block\Adminhtml\Listings\Edit\SaveButton</item>
        </item>
```

SaveButton.php

```
<?php
namespace <Vendor>\<Module>\Block\Adminhtml\Listings\Edit;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

/**
 * Class SaveButton
 */
class SaveButton extends GenericButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        $url = $this->getUrl('properties/listings/update', ['property_id' => $this->getId()]);
        return [
            'label' => __('Save Property'),
            'class' => 'save primary',
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => ['button' => ['event' => 'save']],
                'form-role' => 'save',
            ],
            'sort_order' => 90,
            'action' => $url
        ];
    }
}
```

GenericButton.php

```
<?php
namespace <Vendor>\<Module>\Block\Adminhtml\Listings\Edit;

use Magento\Search\Controller\RegistryConstants;

/**
 * Class GenericButton
 */
class GenericButton
{
    /**
     * Url Builder
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * Registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $registry;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $context->getUrlBuilder();
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    /**
     * Return the synonyms group Id.
     *
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        $data = $this->registry->registry('property_data');
        //return $contact ? $contact->getId() : null;
        return $data['property_id'];
    }

    /**
     * Generate url by route and parameters
     *
     * @param   string $route
     * @param   array $params
     * @return  string
     */
    public function getUrl($route = '', $params = [])
    {
        return $this->urlBuilder->getUrl($route, $params);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.

Because of the submit_url in the provider.js is undefined

```
defaults: {
    clientConfig: {
        urls: {
            save: '${ $.submit_url }',
            beforeSave: '${ $.validate_url }'
        }
    }
},
```

I solved with submit_url under js_config in Datasource

```
<dataSource name="settings_form_data_source">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="brikl/settings/save"/> 
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    .....
```

Source: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139639/uicomponent-form-save-button-not-working